# Streaming MP3 through URL on Android

Tags: android, streaming

I am working on Android Streaming application where I need to play mp3 streams on the handset from a online URL

I can't find any good sample that demonstrates this. Can anybody guide me to a good demo with the sample
source code for this?

I have been googling around but no success. Also few more questions, do all Android versions support mp3 Streaming
without any download?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is pretty straight forward AFAIK. just put the URL of that MP3 file as the source of your media player/audio player, and it will start streaming

Comment: Will this work for all Android versions?

Comment: Android is pretty good in backward compatibility. so if something is working in 1.6, there are high chances that it'll be working in all future versions too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in sdk api demo is there in that api demo the perfect example given you try for that code

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    videotest = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
    videotest.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path1));
    videotest.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videotest.requestFocus();
    videotest.start();
```